# SSH config PasswordAuthentication is not taking effect

Tags: ssh

I have configured ssh on `Debian 7 x64` server with public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

My goal is to disable password authorization via ssh and leave only RSA authorization.

Right now both ways are working. I added these lines in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

and reloaded service with command:
`service ssh reload`

but sill able to login with username and password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Output of `ssh -v` would help.

Comment: @MarkWagner when I run command `ssh -v` it gives me only option list of ssh usage

Comment: Take your full ssh command and run it with `-v` inserted after `ssh `.

Comment: I'm using Putty from windows machine to login server. How can use -v key in command from putty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding those lines to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config